# Problems using bone symmetry in Blender 2.80

Tags: bones, mirror

**I did what was taught in this tutorial:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovzG9T5KKso

**I selected the bones on the side that I made, right-clicked and selected the symmetrize option:**

[image]

**But it did not work:**

[image]

I tried to do the bones on both sides at once, but I didn't know how to do that in this version of blender.

If I'm not mistaken in previous versions, it was just extruding using shift/control (I'm not sure which of the keys exactly) + E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to symmetrize, the bones must have suffixes like *_R* or *.R* or *_L* or *.L*.